# PyTorch Dataloader not loading data properly? Dataset getting corrupted?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, point-clouds, pytorch-dataloader

I have been trying to solve this issue for some time but can't manage. In the PointCloudCompletion ([PCN](https://github.com/qinglew/PCN-PyTorch/)) network, the training results show me something odd. I am loading partial PCs (`Input`)of objects AND the complete (`Ground Truth`) PC of that partial. **The loading works well for partials always. For *complete PCs*, IT ONLY WORKS on the first iteration** The plots show that for the first iteration has nice results, but after the first one, the Ground Truth PC loaded, is incorrect (which is weird because I am loading it):

Iteration one and two of a run (In other runs, the plot of iterations can be any object of the loaded ones. Ground Truth should stay the same, as it's always the same PC file... **It get's corrupted?**):
[image: Iteration 1]
[image: Iteration 2]

You can see in [datasets/shapenet.py](https://github.com/qinglew/PCN-PyTorch/blob/master/dataset/shapenet.py) the loading method. I changed it a bit to be able to input my dataset. In total I have 400 PCs per object, divided in 280 train, 120 val. That is the reason for the modules (`%280`, etc) in the `for` loops. Not very clean, but it's for testing a small dataset. The PC's names go from `0.pcd`, `1.pcd`, and so on. **The complete PC is actually the same always per object**. I was uploading always 1 file, but I decided to make 280+120 copies of it (one per partial instead of one for all partials. I think it shoulnd't matter anyways),  in case it was a problem of opening the same PC several times. It wasn't that.

```
def _load_data(self):

    with open(os.path.join(self.dataroot, '{}.list').format(self.split), 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    if self.category != 'all':
        lines = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(self.cat2id2[self.category]), lines))

    partial_paths, complete_paths = list(), list()
    train_counter = 0
    test_counter = 280 # change to do clean up. 
    total_counter = 0

    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        category, model_id = line.split('/')
        if self.split == 'train':
            for i in range(280):
                partial_paths.append(os.path.join(self.dataroot, self.split, 'partial', category,str(train_counter%280)+'.pcd'))
                complete_paths.append(os.path.join(self.dataroot, self.split, 'complete', category, str(train_counter%280)+'.pcd'))
                train_counter+=1

        else:
            for i in range(120):
                partial_paths.append(os.path.join(self.dataroot, self.split, 'partial', category, str(test_counter)+'.pcd'))
                complete_paths.append(os.path.join(self.dataroot, self.split, 'complete', category, str(test_counter)+'.pcd'))

                test_counter+=1
                if(test_counter == 400):
                    test_counter = 280

                total_counter+=1

    # for i in range (len(complete):
    #     print(i)
    #     count = count+50
    #     d = complete_paths[count]
    #     pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(d)
    #     o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

    return partial_paths, complete_paths
```

I even had that last method (commented) to check if the PCs were correct. They are.

This function is called in the `train.py`

```
train_dataset = ShapeNet('data/PCN', 'train', params.category)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=params.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=params.num_workers)
```

For some reason, the values of the label (Ground Truth, complete PC, as you want to call it) are not being stored properly, or **pytorch is doing something weird with them**. And I checked in it in here:

```
for epoch in range(1, params.epochs + 1):
    # hyperparameter alpha
    if train_step < 10000:
        alpha = 0.01
    elif train_step < 20000:
        alpha = 0.1
    elif epoch < 50000:
        alpha = 0.5
    else:
        alpha = 1.0

    # training
    model.train()
    for i, (p, c) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        p, c = p.to(params.device), c.to(params.device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward propagation
        coarse_pred, dense_pred = model(p)
```

Where the values `p` and `c` are corresponding to the partial and complete PC respectively. By doing some torch conversion, I was able to print the pointclouds. `c` which is the complete, only has the pertaining value during the first epoch. After that, it's like a blank PC. And I am not sure why this is happening.

```
        d = p[i].cpu().numpy()
        e = c[i].cpu().numpy()
        
        print('The pointcloud per dataloader iteration , ', i)
        pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
        pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(d)
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

        pcb = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
        pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(e)
        o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcb])
```

I thought that in this last part, I can replace `c` with the corresponding pointcloud, but I don't know how to know which object it's getting from the dataloader, to load the correct object.

Comment: how do you define `train_dataset`

Comment: It's a path to the dataset, passed with the `ShapeNet` Class, which innerly does the `Shapenet._load_data` that is showed in the first code of this question! , like this: `train_dataset = ShapeNet('data/PCN', 'train', params.category)` @KonstantinosKokos